# Invoking magic method from within script

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to update the script found [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2009-May/005183.html) to work with IPython 0.13.1, and reached a standstill. The script invokes

```
import IPython.ipapi
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()
for var in self.magic_who_ls():
        try:
            pickle.dump(user_ns[var],fout,1)
            saved_vars.append(var)
        except:
            # An object that cannot be pickled was encountered
            print("Unable to save object: %s" % var)
```

I am aware **IPython.ipapi** was moved to **IPython.core.ipapi**, **expose_magic** was renamed to **define_magic** and **magic_who_ls** was renamed to **who_ls**, but I am not being able to invoke **who_ls** from within the script to get the list of namespace variables. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Shouldn't it read `for var in ip.magic_who_ls()`?

Comment: AttributeError: 'TerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'who_ls' (I tried it with who_ls, magic_who_ls doesn't exist anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import IPython
ip = IPython.core.ipapi.get()
for var in ip.run_line_magic('who_ls', ''):
  # potato
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Works for me on `IPython 0.13.1.rc2`